# Only count posts that contain a post excerpt

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to count the orders by a user in Woocommerce. How can I only count the posts that contain a post excerpt?

```
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $customer_id,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );

$customer_orders_count = count($customer_orders);
```

---

I've tried this:

```
$customer_orders_count = 0;
foreach($customer_orders as $order){
  if( $order->has_excerpt() ){
    $customer_orders_count++;
  }
}

if($customer_orders_count == 3){
  $coupon   = "sub50";
}
```

Comment: i think correct syntax is `if (has_excerpt($order)) { statement; }`

Comment: @BRBonn That got it! Thanks... do you want to put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$customer_orders_count = 0;
foreach($customer_orders as $order){
  if( has_excerpt($order) ){
    $customer_orders_count++;
  }
}

if($customer_orders_count == 3){
  $coupon   = "sub50";
}
```